# Binding with converter

Tags: c#, binding, converters

Writing a lot of these for a listview. Seems a little bloated to first set the datacontext and the apply binding to the Text

```
<TextBlock  DataContext="{Binding Path=SiteId, Converter={StaticResource siteConverter},ConverterParameter=SiteId}" Text="{Binding Path=SiteName}" ></TextBlock>
```

Is there to do the binding directly in the text property

EDIT
Added full xaml for clarification

```
   <ListView  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedReport}"  AlternationCount="2" Grid.Row="2" Name="reportList" ItemsSource="{Binding ReportsView}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.ColumnHeaderContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu >
                            <MenuItem Header="Ascending"  />  
                            <MenuItem Header="Descending" />    
                        </ContextMenu>   
                    </GridView.ColumnHeaderContextMenu>   
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Action" CellTemplate="{StaticResource imageCell}" Width="Auto"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Reportname" Width="Auto" CellTemplate="{StaticResource reportNameCell}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Site" Width="Auto" CellTemplate="{StaticResource reportSiteNameCell}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Company" Width="Auto" CellTemplate="{StaticResource reportCompanyNameCell}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DocType}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Created by" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CreatedBy}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Language" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CreatedBy}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Updated" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Updated}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

EDIT
THis is how i load my viewmodel

```
ReportList = reportListService.Open(filePath);
this.reportsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ReportList.Reports);
this.reportsView.SortDescriptions.Add(
new SortDescription("ReportName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

The ReportList only contains siteid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, well... a couple of things first:

1) Why are you passing in the `SiteId` as the ConverterParameter as well as it being the object of the binding. It's redundent... you're passing the same parameter in as the value and parameter of the Convert method?

2) If you are using a `ListView`, bind the `ItemsSource` to a collection (preferably observable), then use a `DataTemplate` as the `ListView.ItemTemplate`. If the DataTemplate is reusable across multiple `ListView`s, then create it as a resource and set the `ItemTemplate` to bind to the resource.

Or... the better solution: Expose things from a view-model that should be. It doesn't sound like "SiteName" is view-related as much as it business-related. So, have your converter logic on your view-model layer instead and expose that additional property.

Comment: +1: That's pretty much what I wanted to say as well (at least as far as the "Or..." part is concerned), but it's definitely easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you set the datacontext of the View itself to a ViewModel class.  Then all you need to do for the controls is:

```
Text="{Binding StringPropertyToBindTo}"
```

Comment: Sorry for being vauge, the property SiteName is not in the viewmodel , only SiteId , thats why i need the conversion

Comment: How do you get the siteName, where does it come from in the code?

Comment: The siteid is a property of a reportclass in my viewmodel. I need to show sitename instead of siteid in a listview and im getting the sitename by sending the siteid to a converter

Comment: Just to clarify, my code works . its just that i seems unecessary to first get datacontext for texblock via converter and then set bining

Comment: why not have the conversion done inside the viewmodel, and when you bind you're getting back the SiteName.

Comment: The datamodel in my viewmodel of reports with different siteids so the function i would need , which does not exist would be a property that takes an argumment which i could bind to

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be implementing a `Site` property in your data context which contains the functionality the converter implements currently. Then you can easily bind to `Site.SiteName`. Just make sure the data context fires it's `PropertyChanged` event for `Site` when `SiteId` is set to avoid nasty surprises.

However, above approach is impractical if the converter is used all over the place with the same parameter for different data contexts without a common interface or with different base classes.

Comment: Sorry for being such a bother , that would mean i would have to change and bloat my datamodel just to show the sitename

Comment: You could also put that logic into another class (the converter?) and only wrap the method call in your ViewModel. That way your VM's code would stay almost as it is and you still have the more convenient binding syntax.

Comment: Edited my question to clarify. Would your answer imply that i create an extra class for the viewmodel which contains property SiteName and then load that class with original data